Why changes from BAS are not reflected in Fiori launchpad?
I have created the custom Fiori application in BAS and deployed to gateway ABAP repository which is central hub ECC system.
Whenever I change something and deployed again, the recent changes are not visible.
please help me solve this
I have tried all the cache clearing TCodes and reports, but nothing worked:

/UI2/INVALIDATE_GLOBAL_CACHES
/UI2/CHIP_SYNCHRONIZE_CACHE
/UI5/APP_INDEX_CALCULATE
/iwfnd/cache_cleanup
/iwbep/cache_cleanup

For my user id, there is no developer role assigned. I am not sure if that has to do anything with the problem.

I have tried all the cache clearing TCodes and reports which tcodes and reports you tried, considering we are speaking about BAS and BTP? kinda makes no sense

Hi, thank you for the reply.
I have tried
/UI2/INVALIDATE_GLOBAL_CACHES
/UI2/CHIP_SYNCHRONIZE_CACHE
/UI5/APP_INDEX_CALCULATE
these reports and /n/iwfnd/cache_cleanup, /n/iwbep/cache_cleanup - these TCodes.
(Since my id doesn't have developer role assigned, please note, somebody else executed this)

okay, you deploy Fiori apps from BAS to on-prem SAPUI ABAP Repository, got it

Thank you for all the replies.
The problem was not about the caches.
In the target mapping, I had to mention the ID same as in the manifest file.
Once I did that problem got solved.

Try to call /UI5/APP_INDEX_CALCULATE followed by /UI2/INVALIDATE_CLIENT_CACHES.
